# date picker is not opening in IE+11 using wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The date picker is opening fine in all the browser

[image]

**Except Internet Explorer**

The ie console shows this error any solution

[image]

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using? It's likely that it's not supported in IE any longer

Comment: its bootstrap-datepicker
and it is supported in explorer because it showing calender 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Comment: In which case there's something wrong in the code you've written on the page. Without seeing that code, we can't help you debug it

Comment: Your screenshot shows an error - did you try to fix that?  Depending on where the error is, it may be that the whole of datepicker.js hasn't run